# Opening a page after Firefox extension install

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to do something similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958893/firefox-extension-opening-a-page-on-install). However, I am using the Add-on SDK and I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Where would I put the code to open the page right after the user has installed my add-on?

Also, I would like to know if there is a way to toggle the add-on bar after installation, and show a panel on top of my add-on widget after installation like Chrome does it after you install an extension.

Answer (score 5):

It isn't obvious, but you can attach functions that get called when the extensions is loaded or unloaded. This is covered in the 'simple extension tutorial' in the docs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Listening_for_load_and_unload

I *think* to implement this in a module you could do something like:

```
var tabs = require("tabs");

exports.main = function (options, callbacks) {
    if (options.loadReason === 'install') {
        tabs.open("http://mozilla.org/");
    }
};
```