# setUninstallURL - in Safari and Firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, safari-extension

We created extensions for Chrome, Firefox and Safari. We want to open a new tab when uninstalling our extension. I found this code for Chrome, but is it possible to do it in Safari and Firefox?

```
switch (platform) {
    case 'chrome':
        try {
            chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL(uninstall_url);
        } catch(e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In place of `manifest.json` Safari extensions use `Info.plist` which is typically generated with [ExtensionBuilder](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/UsingExtensionBuilder/UsingExtensionBuilder.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH2-SW1). As you can see from the provided screenshot, no 'uninstallURL' is available. I suggest testing a [beforeUnload listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) in the global page but this will probably also be triggered during other events like updates, browser closing etc.

As for Firefox, it all depends on the actual API your add-on is based on. You maybe out of luck if you have used the [Addon SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK) or created a [legacy XUL overlay extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions). However, [Restartless bootstrapped extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions) use low-level APIs and the `uninstall` function in [bootstrap.js](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions/bootstrap.js) receives a reason parameter:

```
function uninstall(data, reason) {
    if (reason === ADDON_UNINSTALL) {
        let win = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');
        win.gBrowser.selectedTab = win.gBrowser.addTab(url);
    }
}
```

Good news is a new [WebExtensions API](http://www.arewewebextensionsyet.com/) is coming to Firefox. It is basically identical to the Chrome API. See the [relevant bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1156826)

Comment: We are using Add-on SDK.

Answer (score 2):

From addon sdk you would use this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Listening_for_load_and_unload

That shows you how to listen for load and unload and detect the reason for load/unload solution is from here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31497334/1828637

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work. The function is not called when disabling or uninstalling the extension in Firefox.

Comment: That's weird @Uri can you show us the code you tried, it should work.