# Navigate to a website after installing my firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm using Firefox Add-On SDK 1.1 to build my extension and wondering how I can open a new tab just once after the user installs my extension?

This answer [Opening my page in firefox after installing the addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824998/opening-my-page-in-firefox-after-installing-the-addon) doesn't really help since it's not working in Add-On SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it helps, all you have to do is use [simple-storage](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/packages/addon-kit/simple-storage.html) instead of prefs and [tabs.open](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/packages/addon-kit/tabs.html) instead of gBrowser.addTab:

```js
const tabs = require("tabs");
const storage = require("simple-storage");

if (storage.storage.first_run == undefined) {
    storage.storage.first_run = false;
    tabs.open("https://www.google.com");
}
```